# Grid of responsive squares with independently moving containers horizontally

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, css-grid

I'm trying to make a grid of responsive squares/containers which covers the entire viewport and each row slides horizontally independently. In landscape orientation there are 4 rows, one row is 25vh high, so all together they obviously cover 100% of the viewport height. It is supposed to be an interface adapted to touch screens.

Here's a code example:

```
<div>
  <div className="group-1">
    <Square 1.1 />
    <Square 1.2 />
    <Square 1.3 />
    <Square 1.4 />
    <Square 1.5 />
  </div>
  <div className="group-2">
    <Square 2.1 />
    <Square 2.2 />
    <Square 2.3 />
    <Square 2.4 />
    <Square 2.5 />
  </div>
  <div className="group-3">
    <Square 3.1 />
    <Square 3.2 />
    <Square 3.3 />
    <Square 3.4 />
    <Square 3.5 />
  </div>
  <div className="group-4">
    <Square 4.1 />
    <Square 4.2 />
    <Square 4.3 />
    <Square 4.4 />
    <Square 4.5 />
  </div>
```

And the .css file (I realize this is a poor way to do a square, I just couldn't get it to work in any other way):

```
.group*>Square* {
  width: 25vh;
  height: 25vh;
}

@media (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) {
  .group* {
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory; 
    scrollbar-width: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  };
}

.group*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

The above solution works pretty well in landscape orientation, there are also enough squares visible on the screen by default. In portrait orientation there are also 4 rows, the squares are bigger and there are fewer of them on the screen (obviously):

[image]

[image]

This solution is not pretty, because when I add new squares I have to do it manually and decide which group to add them to. I tryed to wrap one big row of squares in four but I was unable to make each of the rows move horizontally independently of each other.

What I want to do?

I would like to have 4 rows of squares in landscape orientation and 5 rows in portrait orientation. I want to keep this functionality with independently sliding rows horizontally. I'm pretty new to CSS and I don't have any idea how can I get it to work. Is there a way in pure CSS?

Comment: How is the portrait structure defined? In your example code you have fixed in advance what squares are to go in which group. How is that defined/worked out for portrait mode? Or is it true that there are always 4x5 squares in total and it's just one that moves up to the previous row etc? (i.e. the numbering is not meaningful in the example and I'm reading too much into it?)

Comment: It's structured in the same way as the landscape view. That's the problem, I build four groups and have to distribute the squares equally among the individual groups. That's a poor solution but I've no idea how to do it in a nicer way in CSS. The array of squares need not necessarily be 4x5, this was just an example. I want to have 4 rows in landscape orientation and 5 rows in portrait - all rows can expand horizontally from left to right. In addition, I want it to be possible to move each one individually horizontally. I'm not sure if the solution given by @yerme will work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css grid to accomplish something like what you're looking for. I don't think this is exactly the specific layout you want, but if you play around with some of the rules you'll be able to easily adopt it to your liking.

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-auto-rows: 25vh;
    height: calc(100vh - 1rem);
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 640px) {
  .gallery {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}

.gallery div {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
        height: 25vh;
    background: #1a1a1a;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```